# how to update just one item in recyclerview with listAdapter(using diffUtil)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter, android-diffutils

I have a recyclerview using listAdaper.this recyclerview has so many Items(this is chat list).
if i edit a particular item of list , DiffUtil compare all of the items of the  newlist and old list. it takes long time so updating the  list has delay;
is there any way to restrict the Diffutil to compare just particular item?

Comment: check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60328625/9474700

Comment: If you know what that item is, you can trigger the refresh on the list directly. DiffUtil is intended for other purposes.

Comment: @behrad   thanx for response.the answer means diffUtil shouldnt use for my purpose?

Comment: `DiffUtil` will just update the visible changed item (calling necessary "onBindViewHolder()") and with animations.

Comment: @fatemehalizadeh exactly. you can update your chat item as soon as a new message received. no need for whole update.